# Next.js 14.0.3 with next-auth and NestJS Backend: Works in Dev but Fails in Build

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js 14.0.3 application with next-auth for authentication, using an external NestJS backend for authorization and JWT validation. Everything works as expected in the development environment (`npm run dev`), but I encounter an error when trying to build the application for production (`npm run build`).

```
.next/types/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("U:/sid/sid-front/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"), "POST" | "GET" | "HEAD" | "OPTIONS" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | "PATCH" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | ... 5 more ... | "maxDuration", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'authOptions' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'AuthOptions' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

My [...nextauth]/route.ts is:

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

async function refreshToken(token: JWT): Promise<JWT> {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/auth/refresh", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Refresh ${token.backendTokens.refreshToken}`,
    },
  });
  console.log("refreshed");

  const response = await res.json();

  return {
    ...token,
    backendTokens: response,
  };
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "jsmith",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null;
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        const res = await fetch(
          process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/auth/login",
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email,
              password,
            }),
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
        if (res.status == 401) {
          console.log(res.statusText);

          return null;
        }
        const user = await res.json();
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) return { ...token, ...user };

      if (new Date().getTime() < token.backendTokens.expiresIn) return token;

      return await refreshToken(token);
    },

    async session({ token, session }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      session.backendTokens = token.backendTokens;

      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And my next-auth.d.ts:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: string;
    };
    backendTokens: {
      accessToken: string;
      refreshToken: string;
      expiresIn: number;
    };
  }
}

import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    user: {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: string;
    };
    backendTokens: {
      accessToken: string;
      refreshToken: string;
      expiresIn: number;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved authOptions and refreshToken functions to a separated file, exported them from there and imported in route.ts and error resolved.

Comment: I am facing the same error, I tried with Next version 14.0.3 and separated the autoOption to a separate file but still got the same error. I am running the build in Windows.
May I ask you what version of next-auth and node version you are using?